# How to determine the oldest version of Chromium still supported by Angular 2?

Tags: google-chrome, angular, browser, chromium

According to the [Browser Support](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html) documentation for Angular 2, it states that it supports the "latest" version of Google Chrome. I understand this is because Google Chrome is an "evergreen" browser, so most users will always have the latest version. I also am under the impression that Google Chrome is based off of Chromium, and that they share mostly the same code aside from some media codecs that should not affect Angular 2. So this means that Angular 2 also supports the "latest" version of Chromium.

However, the project I am currently developing requires support for users who are using older versions of Google Chrome, or other browsers based off of older versions of Chromium.

I wish to evaluate whether Angular 2 will fit the requirements for the project. To do so, I will need to determine what the oldest version of Chromium still supported by Angular 2 is.

So my question is: **is there an efficient way to determine the oldest version of Chromium still supported by Angular 2, that does not involve downloading every version and testing them one by one?**